Is exponentiation of isometries uniformly continuous in the uniform topology?
Let $(X,d)$ be a (bounded, complete, even polish) metric space, and let $G$ be the group of isometries of $(X,d)$ with the uniform metric $d_u$ defined by $d_u(f,g):=\sup_{x\in X}d(f(x),g(x))$ for all $f$ and $g$ in $G$.
For a fixed positive integer $n$, consider the map $G\rightarrow G$ given by $f\mapsto f^n$ ($f$ composed with itself $n$ times). Is this map uniformly continuous? Is it Lipschitz continuous? In that case, what is a constant?
Since $G$ is a topological group, it is easy to see it is continuous. But i haven't managed to find uniform continuity, and I'm starting to doubt whether it is actually uniformly continuous.
I would appreciate any insight.

It is Lipschitz with constant $\leq n$. Suppose $f,g\in G$ and let $K=d(f,g)$, so $d(f(x),g(x))\leq K$ for all $x\in X$. We want to show that $d(f^n(x),g^n(x))\leq nK$. Let $y=f^{n-1}(x), z=g^{n-1}(x)$. By induction we can assume that $d(y,z)\leq (n-1)K$. Then $$d(f(y), g(z))\leq d(f(y), f(z)) + d(f(z), g(z))=d(y, z) + d(f(z), g(z))\leq d(y,z)+K\leq nK$$
which is what we wanted.
